# How can I store compound data in a struct without copying?

Tags: mojolang

The following program tries to store a `Thing` in a `Holder`:

```
struct Holder:
    var thing: Thing
    fn __init__(inout self, owned thing: Thing):
        self.thing = thing
        pass

struct Thing:
    fn __init__(inout self):

thing = Thing()
Holder(thing^)
```

When I run the program, I get the following error message:

```
error: Expression [59]:8:22: value of type 'Thing' cannot be copied into its destination
        self.thing = thing
```

Here's why I expected this code to run without errors:

- The `^` transfers ownership, so the module scope no longer owns `thing`
- `__init__` takes `Thing` as `owned`

I know I can make the code run by implementing a `__copyinit__` but is there a way to avoid the copy?

When I translate to Rust the program compiles and runs:

```
struct Holder {
    thing: Thing
}

struct Thing {}


fn main() {
    Holder { thing: Thing {} };
}
```

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b54686072598d521d1abeea361d698cd)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `Thing.__moveinit__` function and also pass the ownership between varibales inside the `__init__` function: from `thing` argument variable to `self.thing` member variable

```
struct Thing:
    fn __init__(inout self):
        ...

    fn __moveinit__(inout self, owned other: Self):
        ...

struct Holder:
    var thing: Thing
    fn __init__(inout self, owned thing_arg: Thing):
        self.thing = thing_arg^ # <--- see the transfer operator (^) here

fn main():
    let thing = Thing()
    let holder = Holder(thing^)
```

It's a bit confusing but there are 3 variables instead of 2, if you name all of them `thing` it's easy to miss it:

- varible `thing`
- argument `thing_arg`
- field `self.thing`